# Add elevation to contour vectors using sequential numbering by drawing a line

Tags: arcgis-pro, elevation, contour

I have several contour lines and I want to add the elevation as attribute. I found a tool in ArcGis Pro that would do exactly what I need, select the contours with a line, specify the starting value and increment with a value. The problem is that I need to increment with 0.5 and I am allowed to use only integers. Any ideas on how to add the values?[image]